# Programmatically add a close button to an NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, button, nswindow

I'd like to add a close button to an `NSWindow` programmatically. I can get the button to display, but there are no mouse-over or mouse-down effects. My "selector" never seems to get called when i click the button. I'm not really sure whats wrong and why this is so annoying.

Here is what I've been messing with:

```
closeButton = [NSWindow standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton forStyleMask:self.styleMask];

NSView *themeFrame = [[self contentView] superview];
NSRect c = [themeFrame frame];  // c for "container"
NSRect aV = [closeButton frame];    // aV for "accessory view"
NSRect newFrame = NSMakeRect(                                                c.size.width - aV.size.width - 5,  // x position                                                c.size.height - aV.size.height - 5,    // y position                                           aV.size.width,  // width                                                aV.size.height); // height

[closeButton setFrame:newFrame];    
[themeFrame addSubview:closeButton];
[closeButton setAutoresizingMask:NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMinYMargin];  
[closeButton setEnabled:YES];
[closeButton setTarget:self];
[closeButton setAction:NSSelectorFromString(@"testClick:") ];
```

Where "testClick" is just a memeber function of my class and is defined as such:

```
- (void)testClick:(id)sender
```

The problem seems to be the call to:
    [themeFrame addSubview:closeButton];

where the themeFrame is: `[[self contentView] superview]` Just adding the button to `[self contentView]` works, but I'd like it added to the titlebar.

No Interface Builder please...

Answer (score 0):

Potential issue # 1)

The way you're calling "`NSSelectorFromString`" seems incorrect to me.  I don't think you can pass parameters via this way in Objective C.

Try this:

```
[closeButton setAction: @selector(closeWindow:)];
```

and create a new "`closeWindow:`" action that looks like:

```
- (void) closeWindow: (id) sender;
```

which closes the window.

Potential issue # 2)

Instead of:

```
closeButton = [NSWindow standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton forStyleMask:self.styleMask];
NSView *themeFrame = [[self contentView] superview];
```

Why not use:

```
NSWindow * parentWindow = [[self contentView] window];
if(parentWindow)
{
   closeButton = [parentWindow standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton forStyleMask:self.styleMask];
}
```

Comment: Don't know if `NSSelectorFromString` is bad in itself, but the colon is missing in the method signature, which in itself could cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've added the suggest fixes and updated the original question, however the problem still persists. Specifically: adding my button to the [self contentView] works, the button can call the selector. However adding it to the [[self contentView superview]] results in a button which cannot be clicked (no selector call). I wanted this button to appear in the title bar, not in the content view.

Comment: NSelectorFromString is fine to be used for this, although @selector() is even easier